# Post build event my documents folder generic

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, cmd, post-build-event

I am wondering how to be able to get the my documents path on any machine.

I need to be able to create a new file there and to copy a folder into it.
Here what I got so far, I know its hardcoded so I am looking for some help.

```
1. make text file in:
C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\folder1\Projects\project1\copyfolder\textfile.txt

2. copy folder and contents:
C:\ProgramData\test1\copyfolder\
to
C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\folder1\Projects\project1\copyfolder\
```

Here's what I got so far:

echo. 2>C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\folder1\Projects\project1\copyfolder\textfile.txt

But as you see its hardcoded!

Also would %USERPROFILE%\My Documents\ work?
Thanks

Comment: Just curioud why do you want the documents instead of the project folder?

Comment: Project folder has no read/write access

Comment: The %USERPROFILE%\My Documents\ method would only work if you have enough knowledge of the systems where this is run. First of all it's only "Documents" on Windows 7 and higher so this would be more of a WinXP solution. Second there is no guarantee that the Documents folder is there. It can be moved to any location and has not to stay inside the profile in theory. In praxis you can probably say if this is ever the case in your working environment so it may very well be good enough for you but not a globally working solution

Answer (score 3):

Correct syntax for build events is `$(USERPROFILE)\Documents`

Answer (score 2):

As the visual studio post build is based on MSBuild it should be possible to use a macro that directly accesses the registry (See Registry Properties in the [MSBuild documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx)).

So you can use

```
$(registry:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders@Personal)
```

to query the exact location of the current users Documents folder no matter whether it was moved or not